# How to run a program (C++) on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I see no option to compile and run a program. I'm really confused.

Comment: You forgot to read about what Visual Studio Code is. It is not Visual Studio with Visual C++.

Comment: Try Visual Studio Community Edition for the full thing: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-community

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code does not act as a compiler, it is merely a text editor.

View [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953743/what-exactly-is-visual-studio-code) for more information.

Comment: So, how to run visual studio on Mac then?

Comment: You can't, afaik. You need to use a different IDE altogether. Try looking for C++ IDE's on Mac, Visual Studio Code is not one.