# How to get MSBuild 15 without a full install of Visual Studio?

Tags: sdk, msbuild, .net-core

"MSBuild is now installed in a folder under each version of Visual Studio." However, I do not want to install a full VS on the server. "MSBuild is now available as part of the [.NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download)."

Now that I've installed the .Net Core 2.1 SDK (and the 4.7.2 Framework), what is the path to msbuild.exe?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

MSBuild.exe 15 was found after installing the [VS Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) with no additional packages selected in the install interface.

Edit: Updated link above to go to older downloads.  Expand 2017 panel, click Download, login with a Microsoft account, then you will see Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9) in the list of available downloads.

Edit: increased minor version to 9 to reflect the latest of major version 15.

Edit: You have to join the free "Dev Essentials" if you do not have a subscription. Then you can proceed to "Downloads" menu item and search "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017" to get the proper download button.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe

Comment: I think this answer is outdated. The VS Build Tools link now takes me to a 2019 install, which doesn't have MSBuild.exe in that respective directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\<missing>. If I click on the link to "Older Versions" I only have an option for a full VS 2017 install or for Build Tools from 2015. I don't want the full VS install, but I need some way of getting MSBuild 15.

Comment: V15 of VS Build Tools is now available on the older versions page: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: Leave everything unchecked and it will only install the build tools.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16

Comment: one you click on "Download" for "Visual Studio 2017 and other Products it take to [link](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads) from where you can select and down **Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9)**

Comment: FYI: I followed the instructions above to get to the download and one must have an active subscription to download.

Comment: @TH I updated the answer with the fact that you are compelled to join Dev Essentials to get to the download. Thx.