# Compile C# 7.2 project from command line

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, devenv, c#-7.2

I am creating test automation for my code generation library. 
I have a test project in C# 7.2. The project compiles with Visual Studio without any issues.
My test is updating the code of this project. Then I want the test to compile the project, load the assembly, and verify it works as expected.

I tried both msbuild and csc. Both are complaining that 7.2 is too high for them.

I guess there should be a way to compile the project with devenv, which is already installed and works perfectly via UI.

Is there?

Comment: A [devenv command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2017#example) like this:[devenv SolutionName /Build SolnConfigName /Project ProjName /ProjectConfig ProjConfigName]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C# 7.2 you'll have to use the MSBuild version shipped with VS2017 (Version 15). Assuming that the command line runs on a machine where *VS2017 Professional* is installed, the correct MSBuild path should be

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

Any other version of MSBuild should fail to compile C# 7. Specifically, I am building C# 7.2 projects with MSBuild *15.9* and it works.

#### Edit

You could install MSBuild 15 with the build tools for Visual Studio ([see here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/downloads/)). I don't know fow sure *which* version will be installed, but I assume that it'd be the latest. **Please note** that according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52729945/2249175) the path will be slightly different.

Comment: Glad I could help :)