# Using .Net 4.8 Framework in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-4.0

I'm relatively new to the .NET environment and need to develop in VS Code (no VS available for reasons). I also need to use an assembly, build for the .NET 4 framework, but every single thread only lists .NET Core for VS Code. 
If I understand correctly both are .NET frameworks, but Code can be used on more plattforms and is based on the .NET 2.x/3.x framework?

So my question is, how can I compile and debug C# code with an .NET 4 assembly in VS Code?

I've already tried and installed .NET 4.8 but VS Code still requires Core.

Comment: VS Code is highly extensible and customizable. It would take me wonder, if this weren't possible. Do you have the official C# extension installed? And .net framework 4.8 SDK, I guess? _Maybe_ (not sure, though) you need to install the appropriate project templates, too.

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio Code for .Net Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707095/visual-studio-code-for-net-framework/49824895#49824895)

> First thing, the more recent updates for Visual Studio Code do support
>   building and debugging projects for .NET Framework, but it is very
>   limited:
>
> > The C# extension supports limited full .NET framework debugging. It
> >     can only debug 64-bit applications with portable PDBs.
> >     https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Desktop-.NET-Framework
>
> As it says in OmniSharp (responsible for C# extension) github, the
>   project must be a 64-bit application with portable PDBs.