# Does Visual Studio Online need Node.js, .Net Core or .Net Framework to be installed on your machine to debug and run?

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops

I'm interested in installing and starting up a [Visual Studio Online](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/visual-studio-online/) project in my browser (Chrome) on my Macbook Air.

My project is an Angular App (7+) with a .Net Core Web Api backend and an older .Net Framework project that the .Net Core app connects to over HTTP when I need to send a document over a WCP (SOAP) connection to a web service. So when I need to test the .Net Framework part I switch over to a PC and run/debug the website, but I only need to test that occasionally so I mainly use my Macbook for development.

**QUESTION** - I'd like to see if I can get this project running/developing in [Visual Studio Online](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/visual-studio-online/) on my Macbook's browser (Chrome), but I'm not sure how it works regarding .Net Core and .Net Framework? Do I need to have these SDK's installed on my machine or is everything installed/tested/run through the cloud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[No, your machine doesn't need any dev tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/online/overview/what-is-vsonline#environments), all compute and storage related to development happens in a cloud environment (read: docker containers).

If I were to elaborate, VS Online is built around [decoupling front-ends](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development) (i.e. Desktop VS ([although in private preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/online/quickstarts/vs)), VS Code or Browser-based Visual Studio Online experience) and backends - containers that are created and managed for you in Azure (you also have an option to [DIY tricky setups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/online/reference/configuring) or [self-host on-prem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/online/resources/faq#what-are-self-hosted-environments)).

At [environment creation time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/online/how-to/browser#create-an-environment), you have option to point to a git repository and VS Online will try to figure out your dependencies and configure everything.

One potential gotcha to point out: as far as I am aware the service itself is free, but to unlock full benefit you will need an Azure subscription - running environments seems to be billed at normal Azure rates.

**UPD** having examined my instance of VS online and further checked the docs, I must conclude, these are not full fat VMs but rather Linux docker containers that back your experience. So running windows applications inside environments is probably a no go. (you can [sign up](https://aka.ms/vsfutures-signup) for private preview of Windows Containers, but as of now - only Linux is publicly available)

From what I gathered off your question, it seems you're mostly looking at this for debugging you windows application remotely, which likely leaves you with an option to run a windows VM somewhere and try something along the lines [of this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707095/visual-studio-code-for-net-framework). But it seems there are quite a few limitation which will probably make it even worse for you as mac user.

Comment: I tried to get a project going but as soon as I got to the stage/step where it asked me for my "pay-as-you-go" subscription, I exited as I didn't want to get charged for time/units/etc just for checking out the environment to see if it was something I would like to use.

Comment: What about my .Net Framework project that the VS Code UI/.Net Core app calls? Currently, to run/debug the .Net part, I have to open both VS Code and VS to run the entire app together to test and debug. Would I be able to do this with  Visual Studio Online?

Comment: @user1186050 I guess it is to be expected... Microsoft incurs costs by spinning up a whole VM for you - it only makes sense they charge you for compute. Check out their calculator - the price might be palatable. Also check if you can get free credits (I remember they used to run introductory offers)

Comment: @user1186050 hard to say not knowing your setup, but if it's a stand alone app that you need - you might have to either deploy it somewhere or try to DIY an environment so you older app is preinstalled there. I'm afraid I can't really help much with planning this out

Comment: what questions would you need to ask me to understand if it's possible?

Comment: i'm sorry, I think I misled you to believe it's a piece of cake, but then I realised that windows support is pretty much tied into desktop VS (which you don't have easy access to) and is not public yet. see updated answer - I'll poke around a bit more but it seems grim

Comment: pretty much one action I could suggest would be to gain access to that private preview and trying out your pre-built windows image.

Comment: ya I think a VM is my best bet, but having run VM's on my machine in the past, I concluded my machine isn't powerful enough (2013 MB Air). I just thought it would be nice to have both app's running with VS Online, but just looking through the docs and seeing a short vid, I don't see where I'd be able to run a VS Code and .Net app simultaneously. It looks like it's one or the other...

Comment: you could potentially run the VM in azure and try the VS Code remote debug solution I referred to in my update?

Comment: i got curious and submitted request for access. I'll play around with it when I've got a moment and eventually update the answer. I make no promises, so probably best to not expect me to come back with an update any time soon

Comment: don't spend too much time on it unless you're curious about it yourself. I have a PC at work to use, I'm more curious myself, but don't need to have someone spend that much time on it just to get an answer.

Comment: i love a good challenge and it seems like something i could blog about. cheers