# Support for .NET framework 4.x on visual studio code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, webforms, .net-4.8

I tried looking for support of .NET Framework on Visual studio code. Also there is no support found by me on MVC5, Entity framework 6 DB First, Asp.net Web Forms and WPF.

Visual studio community and other versions allow us to create applications
mentioned above using templates or wizards, which I could not in VS CODE.

Please let me know there is any way to enable the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "support"?

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you for pointing out. Modified the question.

Comment: Oh no, wizards and new file creation are cumbersome in Code. There's a plugin for everything, but nothing compares to Visual Studio. There's for example https://github.com/Microsoft/WebTemplateStudio/

Comment: @CodeCaster I am trying to create WPF , MVC5, Webforms using VS Code on .NET Framework 4.8. Not exactly by means of wizard, but by any means. Is it possible?

Comment: Everything is possible, it all comes down to creating and editing files. The experince for WinForms and WPF in Code is, in my experience, subpar for actual productive work. I mean, look what you need to do to debug .NET Framework projects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707095/visual-studio-code-for-net-framework