.NET framework installation issue
I am trying to install the .NET framework to use it with VS Code, however, I need .NET framework for my tutorial but I can not determine that I have it installed correctly or where is the issue, when I try to go to cmd, the dotnet command does not work.
I get to the regedit throw (windows key + R) then I found the .NET framework there but I think that I just have the runtime pack not the Developer pack that I need (I think):

Now I tried to check that by a command like :
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWAREMicrosoftNET Framework SetupNDPv4Full

which Chat GPT recommended to me and it says that the File was not found I tried to delete all old versions of .NET framework and reinstall it again, it did not work as well, I am all over my head I just need to get it up and running so I can start with my course as fast as I can.
NOTE:

I am on Windows 7 because of the old hardware
Every time I tried to install the .NET framework, it says "Installed successfully".

What do I do to install the .NET framework and be able to use it?

Debugging support for .NET Framework seems to be limited in VSCode, however, have you tried these steps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49824895/10470363

@Visual Studio thank you i read it all it seems like another issue, I don't have the . Net framework installed even though the installer says that (Installed successfully), which means even throw the cmd I can not reach it with the dotnet command.

Which tutorial are you following? Which version of .NET are you installing? The dotnet command is for .NET /.NET Core and not .NET Framework. Sounds like there may be some confusion regarding .NET Framework, .NET Core and .NET.

@phuzi I am following a RoadMape in Arabic. It uses VS 2022, which is simple and straightforward, but on Windows 7, it is not supported. I got my hands on VS Code 2019 after a lot of searching, and now I am stuck with this issue. I am trying to install .Net framework 4.7.2  or 4.8.0 , both of which end up filing.

Could you run the following from windows command or powershell reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP" /s and update the question with the ouput?

@phuzi thank you for helping, finally I have got my hands on vs 2019, which is working with my Windows 7, it is easier for me as a beginner, it came problems-free , thanks a lot for your time.
