How to run an ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio Code?
I work on .NET 4.7. I have an issue: I can't run applications in Visual Studio Code. I don't know how to run it.
Startup page is
http://localhost:22851/WebPages/loginT.aspx

This page opens in Visual Studio 2019, but how to open the page logint.aspx in Visual Studio Code?
Project contains aspx web pages and asx user controls.
Visual Studio Code version is 1.96.2
Screenshot of the app


I think the answer is that it can't be done. Or if it can be done then it would take an enormous amount of tweaking, e.g. see this very long answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707095/visual-studio-code-for-net-framework#49824895 (without any mention of ASP.NET).

In other words, download + adopt the free edition of Visual Studio, and you should be good to go, and work on that project. Not sure exactly what is preventing you from using Visual Studio but without question that is the correct tool to use for such projects. Life is too short to mess around with some alternative road here - use the right tool for this job = Visual Studio.

You can use IIS and IIS Express extension for Visual Studio Code.

i need to open this page http://localhost:22851/WebPages/loginT.aspx using visual studio code
